# MySQL Update multiple columns based on single IF

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have a pretty big query I'm trying to optimize.

It's an `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.
However, I need to only update the line on certain condition. Since I know that you can't use `WHERE` with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, I am using `IF`.

But I need to update two columns based on the exactly same condition. The problem is that the condition is veery long. It's `column1` IN (massive joined select). And having it twice there doesn't seem right either. I would create a temporary table instead, but since this is only needed in the `UPDATE` part and not the `INSERT` one, that would create unnecesary work for some cases.

My question is:

> How can I update multiple columns based on single condition in ON
>   DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `update` statement can refer to values in the `from` clause of `insert . . . select`.  The idea is to take your query and make it a subquery.  Then add one more column which is your calculated column.  You can use this in the `set` clause:

```
insert into table(col1, . . .)
    select . . .
    from  (select cols, . . .,
                  col1 in (complicated stuff here) as IsPresent
           from . . .
          ) t
     on duplicate key update colx = if(t.IsPresent, a, b), coly(if.tIsPresent, d, e);
```

Of course, you may be able to get rid of the subquery (which has its own overhead), but this is the most general approach from your description.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) Documentation you can update more columns

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), c=3
```

Comment: Not exactly I was looking for - I need to update them based on a common condition. The solution marked as correct is the one I was looking for. Thanks anyway...